# Concatenate two columns in SELECT query and get MAX

Tags: sql, abap, opensql

I have a table with BUKRS, GJAHR, MONAT and I want to select the MAX GJAHR & MONAT as follow:

```
SELECT MAX( concat( gjahr, monat ) ) AS year_monat
      FROM zfiou_percentage
        INTO data(lv_year_month)
      WHERE bukrs = '5555' AND
            concat( gjahr, monat ) <= '202001'
      GROUP BY year_monat.
```

So in table we have :

```
BUKRS  GJAHR  MONAT
5555   2019   09   
5555   2019   10  
5555   2019   11  
5555   2020   02
```

How can I get the line `5555 2019 11` ?

Comment: What do you currently get with your code?

Comment: Unfortunately this **MAX( concat( gjahr, monat ) )** is not working.

Comment: What ABAP version do you use?

Comment: ABAP 7.52 SP02 on HANA.

Comment: How exactly is it "not working"? Does the program not compile, is there an error message or is the output not what you're expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The year and month columns (`GJAHR` and `MONAT`) are numerical **text** columns (characters from 0 to 9), but `MAX` accepts only a numerical (not text) column, so you may use `CAST` to convert these "texts" to numbers as follows:

```
SELECT MAX( CAST( gjahr AS DEC ) * 100 + CAST( monat AS DEC ) ) AS year_monat
      FROM bkpf
      WHERE bukrs = '3001' AND
            concat( gjahr, monat ) <= '202001'
        INTO @DATA(lv_year_month).
```

It has been tested in an ABAP 7.52 SP 1 system.

NB: the `CAST` function accepts the `DEC` type only since ABAP 7.50. I use the table `BKPF` instead of `zfiou_percentage` because it exists in all R/3, ECC, S/4 systems.

Comment: Thanks Sandra. The best solution.

Comment: Why exactly are you multiplying the year by 100?

Comment: @Sasku by 100 because Open SQL expects a number for `MAX`, so the month June (06) of year 2020 would be transformed like `to_number('2020') * 100 + to_number('06')` = 202006, then `MAX` can work.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenating the two columns like you are planning to is only possible since version 7.50, as indicated by the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abensql_functions_string.htm). What is your version?

If you cannot get it to work or don't have the required ABAP version, you can do the following. For more information, read up on [subqueries](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw70/7.0.31/en-US/dc/dc7614099b11d295320000e8353423/content.htm?no_cache=true).

```
DATA: p_bukrs   TYPE bukrs,
      lt_result TYPE TABLE OF zfiou_percentage.

SELECT *
  FROM zfiou_percentage
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_result
 WHERE bukrs = p_bukrs 
   AND gjahr >= ALL ( SELECT gjahr
                        FROM zfiou_percentage 
                       WHERE bukrs = p_bukrs )
   AND monat >= ALL ( SELECT monat
                        FROM zfiou_percentage 
                       WHERE bukrs = p_bukrs 
                         AND gjahr >= ALL ( SELECT gjahr
                                              FROM zfiou_percentage 
                                             WHERE bukrs = p_bukrs ) ).
```

**Explanation**:

- select all datasets
- of the z-table
- into the itab (because there could be multiple rows with the same max gjahr and month)
- where:

  1. normal conditions (make sure to use them in every subquery as well)
  2. AND the year is the highest of all years existing in the z-table
  3. AND the month is the highest of all months of the datasets with the highest years

**Edit**: *(Of course you could also select your data in multiple steps, using `SELECT` and `SELECT ... FOR ALL ENTRIES ...`, or `SELECT` and `LOOP`. You will have to think about and test which solution will be the most efficient, easy to understand and suited for your problem.)*

Comment: Eventually include the condition <= 202001 : `AND ( gjahr < '2020' OR gjahr = '2020' AND monat <= '01' )`. NB: it's possible to test the query above in R/3 or S/4 by replacing `ZFIOU_PERCENTAGE` with `BKPF`.

Comment: The question is how to do when the gjahr = 2019 and monat = 06. Here the result is 2019 & 02.

Comment: Wow! Very beautiful but too complicated, concatenating in itab will select it twice as faster performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    gjahr AS year,
    monat AS month
  FROM zfiou_percentage
    INTO TABLE DATA(selected_maxes)
  WHERE bukrs = '5555'
    AND ( gjahr < '2020'
      OR gjahr = '2020' AND monat <= '01' )
  ORDER BY
    gjahr DESC,
    monat DESC
  UP TO 1 ROWS.

DATA(selected_max) = selected_maxes[ 1 ].
DATA(max_date) = |{ selected_max-year }{ selected_max-month }|.
```

Comment: This is not correct as it is looking in 2019 for monat <= 1, namely subrc = 4. I forgot: ORDER BY is not working.

Comment: You cannot use `ORDER BY` and `SELECT SINGLE` in the same statement

Comment: Ha! Can you believe I never noticed that? :-) UP TO 1 ROWS should produce nearly the same thing, however.